# What effect does using Action.async have, since Play uses Netty which is non-blocking

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, netty

Since Netty is a non-blocking server, what effect does changing an action to using `.async`?

```
def index = Action { ... }
```

versus

```
def index = Action.async { ... }
```

I understand that with `.async` you will get a `Future[SimpleResult]`. But since Netty is non-blocking, will Play do something similar under the covers anyway?

What effect will this have on throughput/scalability?  Is this a hard question to answer where it depends on other factors?

**The reason I am asking is, I have my own custom `Action` and I wanted to reset the cookie timeout for every page request so I am doing this which is a `async` call:**

```
object MyAction extends ActionBuilder[abc123] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (abc123[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    ...
    val result: Future[SimpleResult] = block(new abc123(..., result))
    result.map(_.withCookies(...))
  }
}
```

The take away from the above snippet is I am using a `Future[SimpleResult]`, is this similar to calling `Action.async` but this is inside of my Action itself?

I want to understand what effect this will have on my application design.  It seems like just for the ability to set my cookie on a per request basis I have changed from blocking to  non-blocking.   But I am confused since Netty is non-blocking, maybe I haven't really changed anything in reality as it was already async?

Or have I simply created another async call embedded in another one?

**Hoping someone can clarify this with some details and how or what effect this will have in performance/throughput.**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`def index = Action { ... }` is non-blocking you are right.

The purpose of `Action.async` is simply to make it easier to work with `Futures` in your actions.

For example:

```
def index = Action.async {
  val allOptionsFuture: Future[List[UserOption]] = optionService.findAll()
  allOptionFuture map {
    options =>
      Ok(views.html.main(options))
  }
}
```

Here my service returns a `Future`, and to avoid dealing with extracting the result I just map it to a `Future[SimpleResult]` and `Action.async` takes care of the rest.

If my service was returning `List[UserOption]` directly I could just use `Action.apply`, but under the hood it would still be non-blocking.

If you look at `Action` source code, you can even see that `apply` eventually calls `async`:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L432

Comment: i see, so in my "MyAction" what is the net effect of using me using a future and callinf result.map?  And what if i do Myaction.async in my controller?  (compared to using the default Action)

Comment: Well, I thought I answered your question. You should have a look at this page of the documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAsync

Comment: Thanks I read that earlier.  So having a future that calls a future etc. doesn't really effect performance per say?

Comment: @Blankman, correct. Every action is asynchronous. Nesting Futures could only help if you have several time-consuming pieces to an action that aren't related (if you do a rest call for a large xml document and parse it, for example). Breaking it into multiple Futures will ensure that they can be handled by different threads if that's desired.
Note: If you have several DB calls in a single action, strongly consider using a db transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to come across this question, I like the answer from @vptheron, and I also want to share something I read from book "**Reactive Web Applications**", which, I think, is also great.

> The `Action.async` builder expects to be given a function of type `Request => Future[Result]`. Actions declared in this fashion are not much different from plain `Action { request => ... }` calls, the only difference is that Play knows that `Action.async` actions are already asynchronous, so it doesn’t wrap their contents in a future block.
>
> That’s right — Play will by default schedule any Action body to be executed asynchronously against its default web worker pool by wrapping the execution in a future. The only difference between `Action` and `Action.async` is that in the second case, we’re taking care of providing an asynchronous computation.

It also presented one sample:

```
def listFiles = Action { implicit request =>
  val files = new java.io.File(".").listFiles
  Ok(files.map(_.getName).mkString(", "))
}
```

which is problematic, given its use of the blocking `java.io.File` API.

> Here the `java.io.File` API is performing a blocking I/O operation, which means that one of the few threads of Play's web worker pool will be hijacked while the OS figures out the list of files in the execution directory. This is the kind of situation you should avoid at all costs, because it means that the worker pool may run out of threads.

-

> The reactive audit tool, available at https://github.com/octo-online/reactive-audit, aims to point out blocking calls in a project.

Hope it helps, too.