# In Playframework, How to do asynchronous job with form binding within a controller?

Tags: playframework

In my controller, I have a simple form binding and Slick database (delete) operation:

```
def deleteApp = Action { implicit request =>
    deletedAppForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => {
            Redirect(routes.AppController.index())
        },
        form => {
            for (id <- form.idx) {
                appDao.delete(id) // database deleting with Slick
            }

            Redirect(routes.AppController.index())
        }
    )
}
```

You can see that I do the Slick delete within a for-loop, that is because I have a list of entry to delete.
This part is blocking, and I want it to be non-blocking.

I've tried to replace the entire for-loop with:

```
val f: List[Future[Int]] = form.idx.map{appDao.delete(_)}
f.map(_ => Redirect(routes.AppController.index()))
```

And (of course) the compiler doesn't like it.

My question is: In general case, how to do asynchronous job with form binding within a controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the better solution is refine appDao.delete to non-blocking. And after you can use:

```
def deleteApp = Action.async { implicit request =>
        deletedAppForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
            formWithErrors => {
                Future.successful(Redirect(routes.AppController.index()))
            },
            form => {
              Future.sequence(form.idx.map(appDao.delete(_)))
                    .map(_ => Redirect(routes.AppController.index()))                    
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If I change to this, it can not pass the compiler. Cause `Action.async` needs the return type to be `Future[Result]`, that is why I wrap the whole block within `Future`.

Comment: fold returns Future[Result] in both variants, so this example must be compiled.

Comment: Whoops, I miss the `Future` part of `forWithErrors`. I think your answer would be right with a little bit change: `Future.sequence(form.idx.map(appDao.delete(_))).map(_ => Redirect(routes.AppController.index()))`, or my compiler gives error.

Comment: I wrote without console, so may be some typos.

Comment: Would you please change your original post, then I can accept it. I thought it would be helpful to others like me.

Answer (score 1):

Steve , typically the asynchronous part of the transaction is done through [Actions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActions). You may want to try a Action.async action to achieve non blocking. I have tried something similar in the past using JavaActions and Async. On scala you may want to refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166136/what-effect-does-using-action-async-have-since-play-uses-netty-which-is-non-blo) and see if that helps

Comment: I made a little modification, though the code runs, but not sure I made it right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"Maybe" this is correct, though the function works, but I am not sure it is real non-blocking or not.

```
def deleteApp = Action.async { implicit request =>
    Future {
        deletedAppForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
            formWithErrors => {
                Redirect(routes.AppController.index())
            },
            form => {
                for (id <- form.idx) {
                    appDao.delete(id)
                }

                Redirect(routes.AppController.index())
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Now the `Action` becomes `Action.async`, and entire code block is inside `Future` except for `implicit request`.